# How to get the total 'percentage' of RAM in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, ram

Hi I am building an application in C++. I want get the **percentage of RAM** that a windows machine is using. I tried a few codes like:

```cpp
string getRamUsage()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX memInfo;
    memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
    DWORDLONG physMemUsed = memInfo.ullTotalPhys - memInfo.ullAvailPhys;

    return to_string(physMemUsed);
}
```

but it just returns some assembly value. Can I get a solution?

Comment: Eh?  Physical memory is expensive.  I hope my computer is using all of it.

Comment: [The GlobalMemoryStatusEx function stores information in this structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-memorystatusex)

Comment: This really sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you actually _trying_ to solve with this information.

Comment: Define what you mean by "using". If you think of your disk cache then as said above I'd be disappointed if all of my system's ram wasn't being used at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex) to get the data.

```cpp
MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);
GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);

// it already contains the percentage
auto memory_load = statex.dwMemoryLoad; 

// or calculate it from other field if need more digits.
auto memory_load = 1 - (double)statex.ullAvailPhys / statex.ullTotalPhys;
```

note: you should check the return value of `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` in case it fail.

Comment: You should check the return value in your answer.

Comment: @MikeVine added note, not sure it's necessary here though.

Comment: I tried to use this piece of code

```
string getRamUsage()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    DWORD memUsage = statex.dwMemoryLoad;

    return to_string(memUsage);
}
```

It returns 0 instead of returning the memory usage

Comment: @PlayZBhai what? you do not call `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`.

Comment: then? `_MEMORYSTATUSEX`? Well I am really an below intermediate so I am really sorry if I am sounding dumb. I just want a code that returns MEMORY usage in percentage

Comment: Just do as this answer tells you to do. `MEMORYSTATUSEX` is a structure that is initialized by your the OS when you call GlobalMemoryStatusEx(). It does not get any values if you don't call GlobalMemoryStatusEx

Comment: @PlayZBhai I mean, the linked page literally contains a full working example that also shows memory usage in percentage...

Comment: I did what's you did there but I am really confused what I must return in the function

Comment: @PlayZBhai the `dwMemoryLoad` already **is** the percentage, you just need to convert it to `string`.

Comment: I but it returns 0 everytime I run it

Comment: @PlayZBhai **what** return `0`, and, do you at least try to run run the program in the linked page?

Comment: I'll edit the code

Comment: See let me explain, can I dm you anywhere else rather than in the thread so I can explain better?

Comment: @PlayZBhai did you **run the program in the linked page**? does it not works for you in any way?

Comment: YES I did, its QT Program. `QString memUsage = QString::fromUtf8(getRamUsage().c_str());`

Comment: @PlayZBhai so `getRamUsage()` return the correct result right? then you should open a new question for the QT part. it's how StackOverflow supposed to work.

Comment: Did you put `GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&memInfo);` between `memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);` and `DWORDLONG physMemUsed = memInfo.ullTotalPhys - memInfo.ullAvailPhys;`

Comment: yes I tried that, doing it returns some other machine value.  I want to display percentage

Comment: This is not calculating the percentage but the amount of memory used in bytes. For the percentage use `return to_string(memInfo.dwMemoryLoad);`

Comment: phew.. you're a life saver LOL! Thanks for fitting something in my dumb brain

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for your assistance :) // @ PlayZ good it's solved, I've update the answer to be more clear